# take value from a map of certain key and add it as another entrySet in another map

Tags: java

1. My first map

   ```
   Map< String,Map< String,Object>> accounts = new HashMap< String,Map< String,Object>>();
   ```

   Example :

   ```
   {Entry01={DisplayName=Test01, ID=001, Status=A}, 
    Entry01={DisplayName=Test02, ID=002, Status=T}, 
    Entry52={DisplayName=Test52, ID=052, Status=A}}
   ```
2. My second map

   ```
   Map< String,Set< String>> groupMap = new HashMap< String,Set< String>>();
   ```

   Example :

   ```
   {001=[Value01, Value02], 
    002=[Value08, Value09, Value15], 
    013=[Value58, Value89, Value90]}
   ```

Need to compare both these map and based on the ID key value from first map, I need to get the value from my second map and add it back to my first map with the key name and value.

I tired iterating through map but my map has many entries but only certain entry will have value.

Comment: Please give an example with real elements, your text is unclear

Comment: Since I cannot paste the real data, I provided a updated sample from my map, with my next question I will add more clear data.

Comment: WHen i say "real element" just use the ones of your example, instead of the sentence you make at the end. Because I don't think there is a need of "compare" here

Comment: Sure, will use it accordingly from next questions. Thank you for your reply, trying the suggestion provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem well, you need to get `Set<String>` corresponding to `ID` and add it to the same subMap as the `ID` **:**

- Iterate throught the pairs
- get back the `ID`
- get the `Set<String>` from the `ID`
- add the `set` to the value's pair

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> account : accounts.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, Object> accountVal = account.getValue();
    String id = accountVal.getOrDefault("ID", "").toString();
    Set<String> setValues = entitlementMap.getOrDefault(id, Collections.emptySet());
    accountVal.put("name", new HashSet<>(setValues));
}
```

---

With [<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8my10M) you'll see the following content **:**

```
// From
Entry52={Status=A, DisplayName=Test52, ID=052}
Entry01={Status=A, DisplayName=Test01, ID=001}
Entry02={Status=T, DisplayName=Test02, ID=002}

// To 
Entry52={Status=A, DisplayName=Test52, ID=052, name=[]}
Entry01={Status=A, DisplayName=Test01, ID=001, name=[Value01, Value02]}
Entry02={Status=T, DisplayName=Test02, ID=002, name=[Value15, Value09, Value08]}
```

Comment: I tried iterating through each entrySet in my map and there was a lot of manipulations included, getOrDefault method seems fine, thank you.